# How to parse an empty JSON object without error in $.post callback

Tags: jquery

If I return nothing to the following post, I get an AJAX parse error:

```
$.post('user.php', {id: 'job'}, function(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
},'json');
```

How can I avoid it? I want to avoid the server giving any empty answers (like "0") to limit bandwidth consumption (mobile app).

Thanks

Comment: just return an empty JSON object instead of a blank reply. how much bandwidth could an empty JSON `{}` or `[]` be?

Comment: Have you tried removing `'json'` response type declaration? It may work as incorrect JSON could be treated as a string (probably "`0`" string).

Comment: @Tadeck I think you're right, since `JSON.parse('')` throws an error. The nicest way around this is to return a valid JSON response (i.e. `[]` or `{}`). (Actually, `""` is valid JSON, but an empty string is not.)

Comment: @mgraph jQuery parses the JSON before it becomes `data`. no response, no `data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Supporting empty responses to calls for JSON

Remove response type declaration if you know it will differ in the code you have given:

```
$.post('user.php', {id: 'job'}, function(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
});
```

jQuery will give you decoded JSON in `data`, if it receives correct JSON.

### Saving bandwidth

You are trying to save bandwidth by removing 2 chars (like "`{}`" or "`[]`") from the response. This may be pointless (not only because of specific carrier's way of measuring bandwidth usage), as there is also the data sent not in the body of the response, but in its headers. Headers contain [a lot of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses), which includes:

- cache information,
- content type,
- server software information,
- cookie data,
- plus non-standard headers for various purposes,

And every header is in the following format:

```
Header-Field-Name: HeaderFieldValue
```

thus **limiting number of headers sent may be orders of magnitude more efficient than avoiding two mentioned chars in the responses**.

Comment: Good point. I wrongly assumed that if there was nothing to send back, there weren't any headers either. Any tips on reducing the number of headers?

Comment: @chris: There isn't much you can do in addition to looking into list of returned headers (eg. by using in-browser developer tools) and eliminating them / decreasing their lengths one by one (such as storing variables in the session instead of cookie, removing unnecessary headers). Sooner or later you will need to do some trade-offs and you will decide some headers just need to stay.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to avoid the parse error on empty JSON responses:

```
var options = {
                url: 'http://mysite.com/page',
                converters: { "text json": function (json_string) {
                        if ( typeof json_string != 'string' || !$.trim(json_string).length ) {
                            return {};
                        } else {
                            return jQuery.parseJSON( json_string );
                        }
                    } 
                }
            };

$.ajax(options);
```

Note: this solution requires jQuery 1.5 (see http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Converters).

You could also move the converter to $.ajaxSetup() if you want it used with every json request.

I found this useful because Rails 3 anyway returns empty JSON responses along with an HTTP 200 to express successful model deletion, etc - so having jQuery treat that as a failure isn't cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can respond with a HTTP 4XX error to the AJAX call. Then the success callback will not be called.

Comment: Good point. HTTP code is being sent anyway, so changing it to `404` eg. should do the trick. Also that could allow OP to support such responses in error handler. But anyway, I think response headers also count into the bandwidth, so saving 2 chars (like `{}` or `[]`) is rather pointless if the header may have hundreds of chars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set dataType in ajax request e.g

```
$.ajax({url:'user.php', type: "POST", data:{id: 'job'}, dataType:'json',
   success:function(data){
            console.log(data.length);
       }})
```

The jquery will return a parsed JSON object in response . Which you can manipulate as desired.

please check the link for [dataType](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)

Comment: OP is already setting `dataType`, you are not telling anything about what `dataType` to use, and your example has syntax error (`dataType: dataType`, I am not talking about the dots). See [`jQuery.post()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for improving the answer.

Comment: it is still incorrect, JavaScript is not Python, you cannot pass arguments by keyword. You may wish to try it first, eg. on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Tadeck , thanks you saved me from down vote , answer updated .